# Why this doesn't work in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I have a parent component and a child component.
I am passing a method from parent component to child component. This child component calls passed method from parent and sends 'this' (child component's instance) to parent.
Now, If I change any property in child component using instance passed above, it doesn't detect any changes.

For eg,

```
@Component({...})
export class Parent {
  toChild(obj) {
      obj.mssg = "changes"; //this should trigger change detection in child component 
  }
}

Template:
<div>
<child [toChange]="toChange"></child>
</div>

@Component({...})
export class Child {
    mssg:string = "";

    @Input() toChild:Function;

    handleOnClick(evt) {
       this.toChild(this);
    }
}

Template:
<div (click)="handleOnClick($event)">{{mssg}}</div>
```

Comment: format your code better and clarify what you're asking. this is unreadable

Comment: it's better to pass values to the child component rather than function, as you pass values to child component from parent values will be reflected in child component

Comment: if you want to call parent method use EventEmitter...

Comment: updated code, plz check now.

Comment: In the child, the input is called `toChild`, but you're passing it in using `toChange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is not quite right and as other's mentioned ... you have some incorrect names.

I was able to get change detection to work fine without Output properties **using your technique** but corrected syntax.

**Parent component code**

```
  toChild = obj =>
      obj.mssg = "changes"; //this should trigger change detection in child component
```

This defines a property that is a function.

**Parent template**

```
<hello [toChange]="toChild"></hello>
```

Here I'm binding it to the *property* that is holding the function.

**Child component**

```
  mssg: string = "click here";

  @Input() toChange: Function;

  handleOnClick(evt) {
    this.toChange(this);
  }
```

You can find a working stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-osqytg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Hello Deborah!
Thank you for replying on this.
I have seen your course on PS. I am glad you answered this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is using inputs and output events

```
@Component({...})
class Parent{
  mssg: string = '';
  updateChild(){
    this.mssg = "changes"; //this will trigger change detection in child component 
  }
}

<child [mssg]="mssg" (onClick)="updateChild()"></child> 

@Component({...})
class Child{
  @Input()
  mssg:string = "";

  @Output()
  onClick: EvenEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  handleOnClick(){
    this.onClick.next()
  }
}
```

Trying to pass a function from the parent to the child that modifies the child by passing the child as an argument to the function won't work because the component scope isn't bound correctly and this is a bad idea in general as it's crazy convoluted.